# How to change Azimuth result interval of [-PI,+PI] to [0,360]?

Tags: android, math, azimuth

i cant solve the problem of titlename.
like you see in the following sourcecode, ive already tried to add 360 on
my result if the sign is negtive. but it seems it didnt work a well.

**OnSensorChanged()**

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        mAccelerometer = event.values;
    }
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        mGeomagnetic = event.values;
    }
    if (mAccelerometer != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I,
                mAccelerometer, mGeomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            // An dieser Stelle enthält das Array orientation[] die Werte für azimuth, pitch und roll.


                double tempAzimuth = 180 * orientation[0] / Math.PI;

                if(tempAzimuth < 0){
                    swAzimuth = tempAzimuth + 360;
                }
                else{
                    swAzimuth = tempAzimuth;
                }
            //

            //double pitch = 180 * orientation[1] / Math.PI;
            //double roll = 180 * orientation[2] / Math.PI;



            txt.setText(String.valueOf(swAzimuth));

            Log.d("direction", String.valueOf(swAzimuth));
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: never used it but maybe `Math#toDegrees` would work better ?

Comment: i dont get it, but the code above is still working well! PROBLEM SOLVED!

Comment: so what you changed?

Comment: nothing, seems like my smartphone hadnt the newest version